# .load() does not show the content loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a scrip that when the user selects a category it will load the content in a `div`. I also have a script that if you click a `pre` tag will select and copy the text. The thing is that is not working when the content has been loaded, btw sorry for my english  [here a  example](http://letraspiolas.com/mytest.html) and here here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#esto").on("change", function() {
    var vale = this.value
    $("#divcontent").load("http://letraspiolas.com/" + vale + ".html");
  });
});

(function() {
  function selectText(a) {
    var b = document,
      text = a,
      range, selection;
    if (b.body.createTextRange) {
      range = b.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(text);
      range.select()
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
      range = b.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(text);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range)
    }
  }
  preTags = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
  for (var i = 0; i < preTags.length; i++) {
    preTags[i].onclick = function() {
      selectText(this);
      document.execCommand("copy")
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <select id="esto" data-placeholder="select a category...">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="test"> test </option>
    <option value="test1">test1</option></select>

  <div id="divcontent">
    <pre>this text can be select and copy</pre>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the content of the **test.html**:

```
<h3>title</h3>
<div class="kghjghjg">
  <pre>____i want to select this</pre>
  <pre>_____and this</pre>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i understood, try sth like :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready( function(){

    // load event
    $("#esto").on("change", function(){

        var vale = $(this).val();
        $( "#divcontent" ).load("http://letraspiolas.com/"+vale+".html", function() {
            console( "Loaded." );
        });
    });

    // event on pre tag
    $("body").on("click","pre", function(){
        selectText(this);
        document.execCommand("copy")
    });

});

function selectText(a){

    var b=document,text=a,range,selection;
    if(b.body.createTextRange){
        range=b.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select()
    }
    else if(window.getSelection){
        selection=window.getSelection();
        range=b.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range)
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `load()` method for an external url you can use load if the `.html`, `.txt` files are in the same domain. In this case you have to use the `html()` method.

```
$("#divcontent").html('<object data="http://letraspiolas.com/' + vale + '.html">').promise().done(function() {
  console.log('Loaded');
  initPreTags();
});
```

**UPDATE**:
If that is not the problem then you can use `load()` but calling a callback function like this:

```
$("#divcontent").load("http://letraspiolas.com/" + vale + ".html", initPreTags());
```

In this case `initPreTags()` is the callback method that will be executed after the content has been loaded.

Please take a look to you modified code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#esto").on("change", function() {
    var vale = this.value
    $("#divcontent").load("http://letraspiolas.com/" + vale + ".html", initPreTags());
  });

  function initPreTags() {
    console.log('Loaded');
    var preTags = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
    preTags.forEach(function(preTag){
      preTag.addEventListener('click', function() {
        selectText(this);
        document.execCommand('copy');
      });
    });
  }


  function selectText(a) {
    var b = document,
      text = a,
      range, selection;
    if (b.body.createTextRange) {
      range = b.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(text);
      range.select()
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
      range = b.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(text);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <select id="esto" data-placeholder="select a category...">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="test"> test </option>
    <option value="test1">test1</option></select>

  <div id="divcontent">
    <pre>this text can be select and copy</pre>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I expressed wrong I put that example but it was in my domain and was not using http… just the path but is nice to know